# Consumo de Web Services Genexus 15

Tags: c#, webservice, genexus, genexus15

Quiero consumir un WebService que esta publicado en Internet al cual tengo acceso por un proceso que se esta desarrollando, no se puede usar el WSDL Import porque el método que devuelve el servicio posee una trama del WS configurada como `Abstract` lo cual hace dinámica la respuesta y Genexus no la interpreta.

Intenté modificar el `External Object` creando un sdt manual con la trama que devuelve pero el proceso da error.

Las consultas que tengo son:

- Ustedes han realizado el consumo de un WS similar que posea en la trama la propiedad `abstract` mediante el WSDL Import? De ser así me pueden facilitar algún ejemplo o wiki donde acceder?
- Que alternativa me recomiendan usar en caso que el WSDL Import no funcione?, estuve investigando que mediante el HTTP Client y HTTP Request se puede realizar un consumo de WS, tienen un ejemplo que me puedan facilitar?

Estoy desarrollando en la versión Genexus 15 U8 para ambiente web C#, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, sería interesante que añadieras cual es el error que te daba con el proceso que intentaste. Tal como está parece una pregunta demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio, esperaremos a ver si alguien tiene experiencia con tu problema de todas maneras.

Comment: El error presentado usando el [external object] es el siguiente: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.(-10001)

Comment: No me queda del todo claro que significa un "WS configurado como Abstract". Lo que podemos hacer si quieres, es que nos pasas la url del Servicio y podemos intentar aquí consumirlo, ya sea con el WSDL Import (realizando las modificaciones que sean necesarias) o con httpClient y te pasamos como sería. Podemos acceder a ese servicio?